# ION_AUTH :: $this->ion_auth->logged_in() giving me bool-false in MY_Controller

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I have been using code igniter and ion_auth for authentication.

My Directory structure is as given below,

```
Project
  - application
      -config
   - modules
      -admin 
       -config
       -controller 
           **-Login.php**

   - core
      - controllers
         - Admin Controller
      - MY_Controller
```

Login.php is having below line of code,

```
$this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, $remember)
```

above is working.

But after that in other file there is one call for checking logged in user as given below,

```
   $this->ion_auth->logged_in()
```

Above line is not working and if I print var_dump then it shows me bool(false)

Comment: did you load ion_auth as a library in corresponding controller?

Comment: How do you validate `$this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, $remember)` is working? I am assuming you are globally autoloading the `ion_auth` library or loading it in `Admin_Controller` and your controllers that require it extend that controller? In any case, you need to validate that your sessions are being properly saved.

Comment: I am validating by if($this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, $remember)) { console.log('success')}

Comment: Anyway I have found the solution.  I was using codeigniter older versions which was having SESSION issues. After upgrading ci to latest version it is working fine.